# how to link django signals and ajax

Tags: django, ajax, api, django-rest-framework, signals

I am trying to implement a data collection system using iot devices.
currently the data transmission is through an API using django REST framewokrs. That works excellent
I would like to know some approach so that a trigger is generated when it receives data and these on the user's website are refreshed using ajax. maybe the use of signals but would not know how to bind that signal with ajax.
I am somewhat newbie to javascript.
some path should I follow?

Answer (score 0):

An Ajax request is just a normal HTTP request. The request is sent to a normal view. A Django signal is connected by a sender and a receiver. I'm not sure what's being sent in your case, but a prime example that's used in the Django docs is to have a post_save signal for a model object. If an object (from a model) calls save or is created, then a signal is sent. So if you save an object while handling your view logic, then the signal will run.

Is this what you're looking for? If you're thinking of doing something asynchronously so that you can send a response back to the client immediately and process whatever you want later on, then check out celery or Django-q.

Comment: i can in the reception API dispatch a signal, but i dont know how to link this signal to a ajax request or view to refresh part of the page eith the new data. me be i am wrong with the concept.

Comment: i like as user look at the page and if new data is recived part of the page will refreshed.

Comment: You can manually refresh the page using Javascript. If you need to refresh the page, then in your HTTPResponse object (you can manipulate the data using a Django middleware), you can modify the data to include some thing telling your JS to manually refresh the page using `location.reload()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use your model signals. But that's only if you are trying to save something to the database.

Comment: i like to recieve data(this is working trough API), and a page refresh with ajax. it is possible?

Comment: all yes... sorry for the late reply.